# How to use context managers with callback functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager, resource-management

How do you correctly use resources, when the resource is expected to be released asynchronously?

Motivated by `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` emitting a warning, when the temporary directory is cleaned up by the destructor rather than explicitly, and this leading to problems in `PYTHONSTARTUP`. Note that the parameter `ignore_cleanup_errors` does not affect the *warning*.

### Toy example with lexical closures.

Consider e.g. the following nonsense example:

```
import tempfile, os

def make_writer():
    tmpdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    counter = 0
    def writer():
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        filename = os.path.join(tmpdir.name, f"{counter}.dat")
        with open(filename, "w") as fout:
            print(f"{counter = }", file=fout)
        os.system(f"tree '{tmpdir.name}'")
    return writer

writer = make_writer()
writer()
writer()
```

This will output e.g.

```
/tmp/tmp9ke4swfe
└── 1.dat

0 directories, 1 file
/tmp/tmp9ke4swfe
├── 1.dat
└── 2.dat

0 directories, 2 files
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/tempfile.py:934: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/tmp9ke4swfe'>
  _warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
```

Normally, I'd rewrite this to somehow use a context manager, but what, if `writer` is used as e.g. an asynchronous callback? Or a utility to be used in interactive python shells? In that case, using a context manager doesn't seem possible.

### Toy example with a class.

So, next I tried to write a wrapper class, that explicitly cleans up the temporary directory, when *it* is destroyed. Remember, this is going into `PYTHONSTARTUP`, so we can't explicitly clean up the object.

```
import tempfile, os, sys

class Writer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        self.counter = 0
    def __call__(self):
        self.counter += 1
        filename = os.path.join(self.tempdir.name, f"{self.counter}.dat")
        with open(filename, "w") as fout:
            print(f"{self.counter = }", file=fout)
        os.system(f"tree '{self.tempdir.name}'")
    def __del__(self):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        print("Executed after the cleanup warning?")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        self.tempdir.cleanup()

writer = Writer()
writer()
writer()
```

Which generates:

```
/tmp/tmpmwrb2nhf
└── 1.dat

0 directories, 1 file
/tmp/tmpmwrb2nhf
├── 1.dat
└── 2.dat

0 directories, 2 files
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/tempfile.py:934: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/tmpmwrb2nhf'>
  _warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
Executed after the cleanup warning?
```

Note that the warning is already emitted, before the destructor of the manager class is called. That part I currently don't understand at all.

### Toy example using generators

For completeness sake, this also doesn't solve the problem:

```
import tempfile, os

def make_writer():
    def make_writer_obj():
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
            counter = 0
            while True:
                counter += 1
                filename = os.path.join(tempdir, f"{counter}.dat")
                with open(filename, "w") as fout:
                    print(f"{counter = }", file=fout)
                os.system(f"tree '{tempdir}'")
                yield
    writer_obj = make_writer_obj()
    return lambda: next(writer_obj)

writer = make_writer()
writer()
writer()
```

Output:

```
/tmp/tmpa6t11t5e
└── 1.dat

0 directories, 1 file
/tmp/tmpa6t11t5e
├── 1.dat
└── 2.dat

0 directories, 2 files
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/tempfile.py:934: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/tmpa6t11t5e'>
  _warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
```

### Current solution: atexit.register

The current use-case of customizing the interactive shell I have solved by using

```
tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
atexit.register(tempdir.cleanup)
```

The downside of this solution is, that it will potentially do the cleanup unnecessarily late for uses, where cleanup could be performed earlier.

Comment: `with` is a syntactic construct, and as such is not intended to work across lexical boundaries like function definitions. The correct thing to do would be for the code that might use the callback to be with a single `with` statement, even if that means the entire event loop.

Comment: Specifically, `writer` should not be responsible for the temporary directory. It should take an argument (explicitly, or implicitly as a method via some instance attribute), and all uses of `writer` should take place inside something like `with TemporaryDirectory as d: writer = make_writer(d); ...`

Comment: That said, I don't get any `ResourceWarning`s. If the problem is related to not using the temp dir with a `with` statement, I think I would expect the generator solution to work, but I can't differentiate it from the class example.

Comment: This is what monads are for. With and friends are just specific loose implementations. [further reading... On skimming this looks decent](https://www.playfulpython.com/introducing-monads-in-functional-programming/)

Comment: @chepner The warnings started appearing for me after upgrading to Python 3.11.8 from some 3.10 version. Additionally, it may be relevant that I compiled it from source.

Comment: At the moment, `atexit.register` seems to provide a working solution for the case at hand.